# How can I receive to socket input as hexadecimal?

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, binary

I sent a GET message with socket. And I received response message as string. But I want to receive as hexadecimal. But I didn't accomplish. This is my code block as string. Can you help me ?

```
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                    dos.write(requestMessage.getBytes());
                    String data = "";                       
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((data = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(data);
                    }
```

Comment: it means you want to read the input from socket in a `byte[]` format..???

Comment: may this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117791/read-binary-data-from-a-socket

Comment: you are right NiRRaNjAN RauT. it must be byte[] .

Comment: then try with the following answer..it may help you..

Comment: If you want to receive something in hexadecimal notation then it should first of all be sent in hexadecimal notation. Please tell first what is going on.

Comment: `I sent a GET message with socket.` Really? Very special. Usually one sends a GET request with a http component. Please explain why you use a socket directly.

Comment: You are right but this is my graduation project. And we wanted to sent GET message as manually. Actually I didnt want to use socket. But I dont know TCP/IP. Socket already make this layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `BufferedReader` you'll get the input into `String` format..so better way to use `InputStream`...

here is sample code to achieve this.

```
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] read = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len = in.read(read)) > -1) {
            baos.write(read, 0, len);
        }
        // this is the final byte array which contains the data
        // read from Socket
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

after getting the `byte[]` you can convert it to hex string using the following function

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());// here sb is hexadecimal string
```

reference from [java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal)

Comment: Actually I must receive as hexadecimal. I just learned it. https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/issues/detail?id=171. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: you can convert `byte[]` to hex string using `String.format();` method